# Why does "yarn install" raise an ENOENT error when installing esparse?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I have a JavaScript project using npm to manage its dependencies. I'm trying to migrate to Yarn.

When I run `yarn install` in the console, it gives me an error:

> An unexpected error occurred: "ENOENT: no such file or directory,
>   chmod C:\....\node_modules\.bin\esparse"

From what I read on the yarn docs, just running `yarn install` should be enough. Why doesn't this work as expected?

I am using Yarn 0.17.0, npm 2.14.12 and Node 4.2.4.

Comment: Had the same issue, reverted back to yarn v0.16.1

Comment: I revereted back to yarn 0.16.1 and it worked. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Looks like this issue should be fixed in 0.17.2 release: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/1823

Answer (score 20):

The following Solution worked for me

```
rm -rf node_modules **/node_modules
rm -rf yarn.lock **/yarn.lock
yarn cache clean
yarn install
```

Comment: This is not fixing the issue for my case.

Comment: Thanks. I added a script to my package.json so I can run `yarn run clean` for when I face this issue. It is `"clean": "rm -rf node_modules **/node_modules && rm -rf yarn.lock **/yarn.lock && yarn cache clean && yarn install"`

Answer (score 11):

This is a pretty old question, but with latest yarn for now (1.17.3) the same problem arises.

The solution which works for me, although more time consuming, is to delete `yarn.lock` file.

Please keep in mind that afterward, all libraries will get updated to the latest versions according to the rules you specified in `package.json` file

Comment: * delete `yarn.lock` and reinstall packages `yarn install`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue which was resolved by running the following commands:

```
npm install yarn -g --force
yarn --c
rm package-lock.json
rm yarn-lock.json
yarn install
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).